# How to update an SQLite database in a specific row?

Tags: android, sqlite

I tryed this:

```
 public void updateCharacter(String charName, int level, int stamina) 
        {
            ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
            //args.put(KEY_CHAR_NAME, charName);
            args.put(KEY_LEVEL, level);
            args.put(KEY_STAMINA, stamina);


           db.update(CHARACTERS_TABLE, args,  KEY_CHAR_NAME + "=" + charName, null);
        }
```

this is my func call:

```
  db.updateCharacter("myPlayer", 2, 2);
```

Getting this exception:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: myPlayer: , while compiling: UPDATE characters_table SET level=?, stamina=? WHERE charName=myPlayer
```

Im 99% sure i got such a column i can print it out, i see it in a layout a definetly got myPlayer in the first column which is KEY_CHAR_NAME (charName), so what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

> db.update(CHARACTERS_TABLE, args,  KEY_CHAR_NAME + "=? " , new
>   String[]{charName})

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
db.update(CHARACTERS_TABLE, args,  KEY_CHAR_NAME + "=" + charName, null);
```

try this

```
db.update(CHARACTERS_TABLE, args,  KEY_CHAR_NAME + "=" + "charName", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I expect you need to put the character name in quotes. Probably something like:

```
db.update(CHARACTERS_TABLE, args,  KEY_CHAR_NAME + "=\"" + charName + "\"", null);
```